# Push to GitHub fails when using git protocol

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to Github but I am getting the following error

```
fatal: remote error
  You can't push to git://github.com/username/repo.git
  Use https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

I looked on internet and saw that I have to replace git:// with http:// but I already have it set to the correct address.

This is my config:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://github.com/username/repo.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Anyone have any idea what can cause this problem?

Comment: this address is wrong. Setup your ssh key on github and use this address: `git@github.com:username/projectname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case none of the suggested solutions on internet worked. What worked for me in the end was completely uninstalling and reinstalling Git.

- Uninstall git
- Remove any leftover files manually
- **Restart computer**
- Install git again

Restarting computer is the important part, because when i did reinstalling without restarting, it game the same error. Restarting seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

check out git hubs help
https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote#what-can-i-push-to

try this

1. git remote rm origin
2. git remote add origin
3. git@github.com:user/repo.git git push origin master

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see the live part. Did you try Marek R?